# direct a nodejs server to listen to a path

Tags: node.js, path, socket.io, port

I am a beginner to nodejs and socket.io. My question is how can I make a server listen to a path,instead of a port. Usually a nodejs server is like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000);
```

Can I change the port to a path that can direct to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can give a path with port number like this

```
server.listen(path + 3000);
```

It start a UNIX socket server listening for connections on the given path.

You can prefer below link - 
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback